# Phantom 4 Advanced - VirtualStick Control doesn't work

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I have a question about virtual stick control..

I am trying to control a drone using VirtualStick Control.
I'm writing a code that the drone moves when the button is clicked once.
But it doesn't work properly...
When I checked the example, it uses a joystick-type button like a drone controller.
Do I have to control it this way?
Or if any problems exist in my code, please tell me what the problem is...

Here is the code I wrote..

```
public void SendDrone(float a, float b){
    if(DroneController.isVirtualStickControlModeAvailable() != true){
        CallInstance.VirtualStickSetting();
    }

    switch(DroneController.getRollPitchControlMode()){
        case ANGLE:
            DroneController.setRollPitchControlMode(RollPitchControlMode.VELOCITY);
            Log.d("Caution: ", "Change the Mode First!");
            break;

        case VELOCITY:
            DroneController.sendVirtualStickFlightControlData(new FlightControlData(a, b, 0, 0), djiError -> {
                if(djiError != null)
                {
                    Log.d("Warning: ", djiError.getDescription());
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT limited to controlling the Virtual Joystick by any specific UI, the example uses the control as an easy way to demonstrate.

However, you DO need to send a continuous stream of control values; I don't remember exactly but if I remember correctly you must send control values evert few-hundred MS or the Virtual Control times-out and ignores values sent.

Be sure you send values often, without more of your code I'm just taking a guess as the issue but above is a common mistake often seen.